# This is about conditional probability

Tags: conditional-probability

At LaGuardia Airport for a certain nightly flight, the probability that it will rain is $0.13$ and the probability that the flight will be delayed is $0.18$. The probability that it will not rain and the flight will leave on time is $0.79$. What is the probability that the flight would be delayed when it is not raining?

Im not sure with my solution:

$A$:event that it rains

$B$ : event that flight is delayed

P(A)=0.13

P(B)=0.18

P((NOT A) AND (NOT B))= 0.79

1- P(A OR B)= 0.79

P(A OR B)= 0.21

P(A OR B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A AND B)

0.21=0.13 +0.18 - P(A AND B)

P(A AND B)=0.1

P(B|(NOTA)) = 0.18-0.1=$\boxed{0.08}$

Answer (score 1):

> What is the probability that the flight would be delayed when it is not raining?

the sentence is a little ambiguous. If you mean "flight delayed AND not raining " your result is correct.

But if you mean "flight delayed given that it is not raining" the result is $\frac{8}{87}$

Comment: Where did I go wrong?